HTML Report to send mail after the Release pipeline completes with details
I have written a html report which need to send after the release pipeline is completed for this i have added a Send-mail task in ADO and used the below HTML script, but when the pipeline completes, my mail have the HTM report as a entire body and the buttons are not getting visible as properly as when i test the same in HTML compiler.
I need the HTML report should be same as the output from HTML Compiler - https://onecompiler.com/html/
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
<head>  
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <title>QA Beta - Release Completed</title>  
    <style>  
        body {  
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;  
            background-color: #f4f4f4;  
            margin: 0;  
            padding: 20px; /* Added padding for better spacing around content */  
            text-align: left; /* Centering text body */  
        }  
        .container {  
            max-width: 600px; /* Set a maximum width */  
            width: 100%; /* Make it responsive */  
            background-color: #ffffff;  
            border-radius: 5px;  
            box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);  
            margin: 0 auto; /* Center the container */  
            padding: 20px; /* Padding inside the container */  
        }  
        .header {  
            background-color: #007bff;  
            color: white;  
            padding: 10px;  
            border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0; 
            text-align: center;
        }  
        h1 {  
            margin: 0;  
        }  
        h2 {  
            color: #007bff;  
            margin-top: 20px;  
        }  
        p {  
            color: #555;  
        }  
        a {  
            display: inline-block;  
            padding: 10px 20px;  
            margin: 10px 0;  
            background-color: #007bff;  
            color: white;  
            text-decoration: none;  
            border-radius: 5px;  
        }  
        .table-container {  
            overflow-x: auto; /* Allow horizontal scroll on small screens */  
            display: flex;  
            justify-content: center; /* Center table in the container */  
            margin: 20px 0; /* Space above and below the table */  
        }  
        table {  
            width: 100%; /* Full width for better responsiveness */  
            border-collapse: collapse;  
            max-width: 100%; /* Ensure the table doesn't exceed the container width */  
        }  
        th, td {  
            border: 1px solid #ddd;  
            padding: 8px;  
            text-align: left; /* Left-align table data */  
        }  
        th {  
            background-color: #f2f2f2;  
        }  
    </style>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <div class="container">  
        <div class="header">  
            <h1>QA Beta - Release Completed</h1>  
        </div>  
        <p>Dear Cheetah Squad,</p>  
        <p>We are pleased to inform you that the release pipeline process has been completed successfully. Please review the changes and verify the functionality of the application in the QA Beta environment.</p>  
        <p>If you encounter any issues, please reach out to the DevOps team for resolution.</p>  

        <a href="#">View Beta</a>  
        <a href="#">View Alpha</a>  

        <h2>Release Pipeline Information</h2>  
        <div class="table-container">  
            <table>  
                <tr>  
                    <th>Field</th>  
                    <th>Value</th>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>Build Number</td>  
                    <td>$env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>Branch Name</td>  
                    <td>$env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>Deployment Start Time</td>  
                    <td>$env:RELEASE_DEPLOYMENT_STARTTIME</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>Requested For</td>  
                    <td>$env:RELEASE_DEPLOYMENT_REQUESTEDFOR</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>Requested For Email</td>  
                    <td>$env:RELEASE_DEPLOYMENT_REQUESTEDFOREMAIL</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>Release Environment Name</td>  
                    <td>$env:RELEASE_ENVIRONMENTNAME</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td>Release Name</td>  
                    <td>$env:RELEASE_RELEASENAME</td>  
                </tr>  
            </table>  
        </div>  

        <p>Release Web URL: <a href="Release-URL">Release-URL</a></p>  
    </div>  
</body>  
</html>

HTML Compiler Output:

Mail Body Output:

